# React-nice-calendar is missing a year

Tags: reactjs, react-calendar

I am using **react-nice-calender** in my application.
The problem is that the year is missing from the calendar as you see in the image.
How can I fix that!

The code :

```
 const [date, setDate] = useState();

   <DatePickerCalendar
          date={date}
          onDateChange={setDate}
          locale={enGB}
     />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the year you have to format the date with date-fns dependencie so I take the example from:
https://reactnicedates.hernansartorio.com/

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { format } from 'date-fns'
import { enGB } from 'date-fns/locale'
import { DatePickerCalendar } from 'react-nice-dates'
import 'react-nice-dates/build/style.css'
function DatePickerCalendarExample() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState()
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        Selected date: {date ? format(date, 'dd MMM yyyy', { locale: enGB }) : 'none'}.
      </p>
      <DatePickerCalendar date={date} onDateChange={setDate} locale={enGB} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here you have a codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/datepicker-default-example-0kn7i

If you are in the current year it wont appear:

2021(current year):
[image: Example 2021(current year)]

2023:
[image: Example 2023]

Comment: Thanks, But I want to show the current year !! there is no way to do that  ?

Comment: @amanirose I don't think so... You could show the current year with the example below, formatting the date

Answer (score 0):

react-nice-calendar doesn't display the current year. I've struggled with the same issue and found an elegant workaround.
It is possible to hide the month with CSS in the upper navigation and then add your own month.

1. Hide the built-in month:

```css
.nice-dates-navigation_current {
  display: none;
}
```

2. Add your own month and year with proper formatting and styling

```js
<p className="calendar__current-date"> 
    {selectedDate.month}
</p>
<Calendar
    locale={enGB}
    month={selectedDate.date}
    onMonthChange={handleMonthChange}
/>
```

3. Finally manage the state of the `Calendar`

```js
  import { format } from 'date-fns'
 
  ...

  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState<{
    date: Date
    month: string
  }>({
    date: new Date(),
    month: format(new Date(), 'MMMM yyyy', { locale: enGB })
  })

...

  const handleMonthChange = (date: any) => setSelectedDate({
    date,
    month: format(date, 'MMMM yyyy', { locale: enGB })
  })
```